# How to loop through CSV file with get request in jmeter

Tags: http, post, jmeter, request

The second HTTP Post Request in Jmeter always is failing.

I am trying to run my test script when you have to click on (snap) twice in two buttons. The first is passing but the second always is failing, and because of it the next step delete them is failing for the second button. I tried to add the timeout time 10000 milliseconds in failing request and then Constant Timer as well but on both of the them are failing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve and where your problem is.

Generic hints are:

1. HTTP Status 404 means "Not Found" so you need to double check the request's URL. It can be done using i.e. [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
2. With default [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of "All Threads" of the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) each JMeter thread (virtual user) will read the next line from the CSV file on each iteration of Thread Group (or [Logic Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)). If you're looking for a different behaviour we'll need to see at least 3 first lines of your CSV file and how you're going to use this data in requests.